# Adding data to the existing Excel sheet using Epplus LoadFromCollection() is corrupting the Excel Workbook

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I have an Excel template stored which has around 25 sheets with some standard data already stored in those sheets. And I fetch the same template and fill the data to the existing sheets in it using `LoadFromCollection` method which corrupts the work book; I get an error

> File Is corrupt cannot be opened

Get the file stored in S3 and pass the responseStream to Excel Package. Worksheet1 has the some data in cells till row 4 and column 4.

```
List listOfDummyData = someData;
MemoryStream outPutStream = new MemoryStream();

using (ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(file.ResponseStream))
{
    ExcelWorksheets workSheets = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets;

    var worksheet = workSheets["worksheet1"];
    worksheet.Cells[4, 4, 4, 9].Clear();
    worksheet.Cells[4, 4, 4, 9].LoadFromCollection(listOfDummyData);    
    workSheets.saveAs(outPutStream);
}
```

Again this `outPutStream` is stored to aws S3. And when downloading the file again, it will be corrupted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the `worksheet.Cells[4, 4, 4, 9].Clear();` line was the culprit , Clear method was removing the all the existing formats of cells which use to cause the file corruption.